# How to login with a form that has randomly generated username and password input names

Tags: ruby, forms, mechanize

I'm trying to login using a form which has no input names. The input names for the username and password form are randomly generated and change every time.

This is what I have so far:

```
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new

a.get('https://mijn.ing.nl/internetbankieren/SesamLoginServlet') do |page|

    login_form = page.forms.first

    login_form.username = '###'
    login_form.password = '###'

    dashboard_page = a.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)

    # Check if the login was successfull
    puts check_1 = dashboard_page.title == 'Mijn ING Overzicht  - Mijn ING' ?  "CHECK 1 LOGIN SUCCESS" : "CHECK 1 LOGIN FAIL"

end
```

Here's the html code for the form:

```
<form action="/internetbankieren/SesamLoginServlet" autocomplete="off" class=
"" id="login" method="post" name="login">

  # Username (gebruikersnaam means username)
  <div class="form_element" id="gebruikersnaam">
    <label for="ah80VpuXfVPqNLULr">Gebruikersnaam</label>

    <div class="tooltip-icon"></div><input autofocus="autofocus" class=
    "firstfield" id="ah80VpuXfVPqNLULr" maxlength="20" name=
    "ah80VpuXfVPqNLULr" size="25" tabindex="1" type="text" value="">
  </div>

  # Password (wachtwoord means password)
  <div class="form_element" id="wachtwoord">
    <label for="ayp5rL2ao299ii2DG">Wachtwoord</label>

    <div class="tooltip-icon"></div><input class="" id="ayp5rL2ao299ii2DG"
    maxlength="20" name="ayp5rL2ao299ii2DG" size="25" tabindex="2" type=
    "password">

    <div class="notification hide-element">
      <div class="notification-icon notification-error"></div>

      <div class="notification-message"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_element nolabel">
    <input id="aU1MyDLNfulG_xPJy" name="aU1MyDLNfulG_xPJy" tabindex="3" type=
    "checkbox"><label for="aU1MyDLNfulG_xPJy">Onthoud mijn
    gebruikersnaam</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form_element nolabel">
    <button class="submit" tabindex="4" title="Inloggen" type=
    "submit"><span>Inloggen</span></button>
  </div>

  <div class="form_element nolabel">
    <a class="link newWindow" href=
    "/internetbankieren/RequestAuthorisationLostCodesServlet" title=
    "">Inlogcodes vergeten?</a>
  </div><script language="javascript">
                          document.write("<INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='aJSJNaIvkvGj4Mzr2' value='" + urlEncode(add_deviceprint()) +"'>");
  </script><input name="aJSJNaIvkvGj4Mzr2" type="hidden" value=
  "version%3D2%26pm%5Ffpua%3Dmozilla%2F5%2E0%20%28macintosh%3B%20intel%20mac%20os%20x%2010%5F9%5F0%29%20applewebkit%2F537%2E36%20%28khtml%2C%20like%20gecko%29%20chrome%2F31%2E0%2E1650%2E63%20safari%2F537%2E36%7C5%2E0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010%5F9%5F0%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537%2E36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F31%2E0%2E1650%2E63%20Safari%2F537%2E36%7CMacIntel%26pm%5Ffpsc%3D24%7C1920%7C1080%7C1058%26pm%5Ffpsw%3D%26pm%5Ffptz%3D1%26pm%5Ffpln%3Dlang%3Den%2DUS%7Csyslang%3D%7Cuserlang%3D%26pm%5Ffpjv%3D1%26pm%5Ffpco%3D1%26pm%5Ffpasw%3Dwidevinecdmadapter%7Cpepperflashplayer%7Cinternal%2Dremot#%2Dviewer%7Cppgooglenaclpluginchrome%7Cpdf%7Cadobeexmandetect%7Cdefault%20browser%7Cdymo%20npapi%20addin%7Cflash%20player%7Cflip4mac%20wmv%20plugin%7Cjavaappletplugin%7Cquicktime%20plugin%7Csharepointbrowserplugin%7Csilverlight%26pm%5Ffpan%3DNetscape%26pm%5Ffpacn%3DMozilla%26pm%5Ffpol%3Dtrue%26pm%5Ffposp%3D%26pm%5Ffpup%3D%26pm%5Ffpsaw%3D1920%26pm%5Ffpspd%3D24%26pm%5Ffpsbd%3D%26pm%5Ffpsdx%3D%26pm%5Ffpsdy%3D%26pm%5Ffpslx%3D%26pm%5Ffpsly%3D%26pm%5Ffpsfse%3D%26pm%5Ffpsui%3D">
  <input id="lptr" name="lptr" type="hidden" value=
  "{&quot;v4a&quot;:{&quot;r&quot;:&quot;0&quot;},&quot;v4b&quot;:{&quot;f&quot;:&quot;0&quot;},&quot;v7&quot;:{&quot;s&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;v4&quot;:{&quot;j&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;timestamp&quot;:&quot;2013-12-18 11:37:22&quot;,&quot;ki&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;v6&quot;:{&quot;u&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;k&quot;:&quot;&quot;}}">
  <input id="lpts" name="lpts" type="hidden" value=
  "8dcca1458144f35323cea6cc160c6e72e92f323a33b33e9fcd1a71263361db1b">
</form>
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/form.rb:217:in `method_missing': undefined method `username=' for #<Mechanize::Form:0x007f9e8c64c648> (NoMethodError)
    from ing.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:442:in `get'
    from ing.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

What's the best way to submit this kind of login form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by storing the randomly generated input names into variables and using them to identify the input fields.

Here's the code:

```
require 'mechanize'

# Instantiate a new Mechanize object
a = Mechanize.new

# Fetch URL with Mechanize
a.get('https://mijn.ing.nl/internetbankieren/SesamLoginServlet') do |page|
    a.follow_meta_refresh = true

    login_form = page.forms.first

    # Store the randomly generated input names into variables
    username_input_name = login_form.fields[0].name
    password_input_name = login_form.fields[1].name

    # Fill in the username and password form
    login_form.field_with(:name => username_input_name).value = 'username'
    login_form.field_with(:name => password_input_name).value = 'password'

    # Login
    dashboard_page = login_form.submit

    # Check if the login was successfull
    puts    "=================="
    puts check_1 = dashboard_page.title == 'Mijn ING Overzicht  - Mijn ING' ?  "CHECK 1 LOGIN SUCCESS" : "CHECK 1 LOGIN FAIL"
    puts    "=================="
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to:

```
a.follow_meta_refresh = true
```